# Google not index my Custom 404 page ?why?

Tags: custom-field, customization, 404-error, google-search

I have a movie site.
When i create First Look of that movie there also created further links related to that movie in the end of the Post using meta tags.

For Example

Movie HD Videos

Movie Mp3 Songs

Movie Trailer

And, in future whenever i create same links with which created in the end of every Post
but google is not indexing that pages even Header response is 200 but google dont indexing my temporary created links.

How To Solve this issue?

Even Page Title Description keyword everything is given in that page but still Google don't index that page relating to that movie but still google not indexing those pages mostly... but i think normally Google index every link on that page
what problem can be possible ?

Answer (score 2):

A 404 page should *never* be indexed.  A 404 response is an error message indicating that a page doesn't exist.

If your site is sending traffic to a 404 page, Google won't index the page.  **This is an expected behavior!**

If your "404" page isn't returning a 404 error, then it's *not* a 404 page.

From the sound of things, your temporarily-created links are in fact temporary.  Google will not (and should not) index "temporary" content.